# How to add event listeners on handlebars template in a backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

So I'm fairly new to Backbone and am trying to create a navigation within a view. I'm using Handlebars for templating and am not sure how I would bind data to it from Backbone. I'm trying to use the render method to put the template partial _nav.html into the current super view. The problem is that my event handlers are undefined because handlebars can't compile before the page loads. Is there a way to achieve this through a view or some other way. THANKS!

```
    var NavView = Backbone.View.extend({

        navTemplate: Handlebars.compile(navTemplate),

        events: {
            'click #filter': 'goFilter'
        },

        initialize: function(){

            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        },

        render: function(){

            $(this.el).html(this.navTemplate({
                title: "Site Title",
                nav: [
                    {title: "Filter"},
                    {title: "Search"},
                    {title: "About"},
                    {title: "Submit"}
                ] 
            }));

            return this;
        }

        goFilter: function(){
            alert("YEAHHH");
        }

    });

    return NavView;
```

Comment: So `Handlebars.compile` is failing because there is no `navTemplate`?

Comment: navTemplate has been passed in by requirejs as a "text!"

Comment: Then I'm confused, I don't know what you mean by "The problem is that my event handlers are undefined because handlebars can't compile before the page loads". You do have a `#filter` element inside your template, right?

Comment: Yeah! But the events hash binds all the handlers before the dynamic title gets put into the template as an id. So how would I render the template first before the events are bound?

Comment: But the `events` are bound to the view's `el` using the delegation form of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so it shouldn't matter.